# React - Table with inputs that dynamically updates parent state. Logical issue

Tags: reactjs, components, parent-child, dynamically-generated

I'm new in react development and unfortunately still thinking like an AngularJS developer. I want to update the application state data using child table components. I developed a basic solution like below but I'm not sure about whether is my solution efficient or not. Also it will be wonderful if you suggest me some materials to learn underlying philosophy of ReactJS. Thank you for any suggestions.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            data:
                [
                    {
                        "id":1,
                        "name":"Foo",
                        "age":"20"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":2,
                        "name":"Bar",
                        "age":"30"
                    },
                    {
                        "id":3,
                        "name":"Baz",
                        "age":"40"
                    }
                ]
        }
        this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this);
    }
    updateState(e){
        const cpy = this.state.data.slice();
        this.setState({data:cpy});
    }
  render() {
      return <div className="App">
          <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-hover">
                  <thead>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Updated Name</th>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  {
                      this.state.data.map((x,i) => <TableRow key={i} data={x} updateHandler={this.updateState}></TableRow>)
                  }
                  </tbody>
              </table>
          </div>
      </div>;
  }
}

class TableRow extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.updateInput = this.updateInput.bind(this);
    }
    updateInput(e){
        this.props.data.name = e.target.value;
        this.props.updateHandler();
    }

    render(){
        return <tr>
            <td>{this.props.data.id}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.name}</td>
            <td>{this.props.data.age}</td>
            <td><input type="text" value={this.props.data.name} onChange={this.updateInput} /></td>
        </tr>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to check the docs from official [reactjs.org](https://reactjs.org) website.

- https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html (practical guide)
- https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html (theory guide)

As for your code, I think the main mistake you make is that you mutate your props in the *TableRow* component *updateInput* method:

```
this.props.data.name = e.target.value;
```

Which is not the way how you should handle changing data in React. I'd suggest something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "Foo",
        age: "20"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Bar",
        age: "30"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Baz",
        age: "40"
      }
    ]
  };

  handleNameUpdate = (id, name) => {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const newData = data.map(row => {
      if (row.id === id) {
        return {
          ...row,
          name
        };
      }
      return row;
    });
    this.setState({ data: newData });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="table-responsive">
          <table className="table table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Updated Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.data.map(row => (
                <TableRow
                  key={row.id}
                  data={row}
                  onNameUpdate={this.handleNameUpdate}
                />
              ))}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class TableRow extends Component {
  handleChange = e => {
    this.props.onNameUpdate(this.props.data.id, e.target.value);
  };

  render() {
    const {
      data: { id, name, age }
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{id}</td>
        <td>{name}</td>
        <td>{age}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Hope this helps a bit! Wish you good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. Your approach seems technically robust.